# Can i do all my work in a broadcastreceiver instead of spinning off a service?

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

I understand that it is a standard pattern for listening for events using a BroadcastReciever and from within the onReceive() method to spin off a Service to do the work related to that event. 
My question is that is there anything stopping me from performing all my work (let's saying some database transactions) in the receiver itself? Sometimes, the work is so small that it might not mandate the creation of a service. Is this legit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your work is supposed to occur on the main thread and the work is relatively quick.  You get IIRC about 2 seconds before you'll get an ANR crash.  If you only have a few milliseconds of work there's no reason to start a service.